# How to pass Json value to Ampscript variable so I can call this ampscript at any component of the email template

Tags: ampscript, json

Im new to Ampscript, maybe here is the place I can get help.
My objects are:

1. get Json with Ampscript after calling an endpoint;
2. parse the Json with Ampscript(or combined with SSJS) to save the values in the Json to Ampscript variable.

The 1st one is implemented, I can use HttpGET; I am stuck on 2nd one.
I have tried this way:

```
%%[ var @var1 
    set @var1 = "https://qa4-nearby-listings.rexagents.com/marketing_cloud/email?subscriberKey=0030m00000ZOGdzAAH" 
    var @getStatus, @content 
    set @content = HttpGET(@var1, false, 2, @getStatus)
]%% 

{{.dataobject JsonVar type=variable source=@content maxrows=20}} 
    {{.data}} 
        {"target":"@content"} 
    {{/data}} 
{{/dataobject}}

{{#each JsonVar}} 
    Variable.SetValue("@bed", {{bedrooms}})
    Variable.SetValue("@bath", {{bathrooms}})
{{/each}}
```

However, the results shows
"Variable.SetValue("@bed", 2)
Variable.SetValue("@bath", 3)"

what is the proper way to save the value into a Ampscript variable.

Comment: If you're working with JSON, I'd recommend just skipping AMPScript entirely and go with SSJS all the way. If you're working with XML, AMPScript is the choice (I tend to use XSLT, for rendering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to use SSJS for the entire functionality, if you response data is in JSON format.
Below is a sample code, where you can fetch details from an endpoint, parse the JSON and store in a Data Extension. If you want this data to be displayed in an email, then you can run this script in Automation Studio. Store the response data in DE and then use Ampscript in email to display the data.

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core","1.0");
  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

  var deObjArr = [];
 var dataRows = ["412","66"];
  
  if (dataRows) {
    var rowBatchSize = dataRows.length;


    for(var i = 0; i < rowBatchSize; i++)  {
            var status = [0];
            var store = dataRows[i];

     //var store = dataRows[i];
      var url = "endpointurl"+ store +"/?output=json";
      var offers = Platform.Function.HTTPGet(url,false,0,null,null,status);

      if(status[0] == 0) {
        var offersJson = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(offers);

        if (offersJson) {
          var offersJsonIFO = offersJson.IFO.length;
          var offersJsonTRO = offersJson.TRO.length;
          var ifo, tro;

         // Write("<br />IFO Lenght<br />");
         // Write(offersJsonIFO);
          //Write("<br />TRO Lenght<br />");
             Write(Stringify(url));

          if (offersJsonIFO > 0) {
            var json = offersJson.IFO;
            for(var j = 0; j < offersJsonIFO; j++)  {
               var offerId = json[j]['id'];
               var offerType = json[j]['type'];
               var articleNumber = json[j]['art_number'];
               var salesPrice = json[j]['sales_price'];
               var position = json[j]['position'];
               var dateFrom = json[j]['date_from'];
               var dateTill = json[j]['date_till'];
               var dateRange = json[j]['daterange'];
               var name = json[j]['name'];
             

               var deObj = {
                 CustomerKey: 'DataExtensionExternalKey',
                 Properties: [
                   { Name: 'OFFER_ID',Value: offerId },
                   { Name: 'OFFER_TYPE',Value: offerType },
                   { Name: 'ARTICLE_NUMBER',Value: articleNumber },
                   { Name: 'SALES_PRICE',Value: salesPrice },
                   { Name: 'POSITION',Value: position },
                   { Name: 'VALID_FROM',Value: dateFrom },
                   { Name: 'VALID_TILL',Value: dateTill },
                   { Name: 'DATE_RANGE',Value: dateRange },
                   { Name: 'NAME',Value: name },
                   { Name: 'STORE_ID',Value: store }
                ]
              };
              deObjArr.push(deObj);
              var offersReq = prox.createItem("DataExtensionObject", deObj);
            }
          }
        } 
      }
    }
    Write("<br /><br />");
    Write(Stringify(offersReq));

    var offersReq = prox.createBatch("DataExtensionObject", deObjArr);

   // Write("<br /><br />");
   // Write(Stringify(offersReq));
  } 
</script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```